# Stop propagation of all events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I am trying to handle Backspace key press of a user. I have 2 handlers bound to one input element. Since it is not possible to detect key press in the onChange event handler, I have to do it in the onKeyDown. I want to stop the propagation of onChange event when backspace is pressed (and handled in the onKeyDown event handler). Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: this doesn't stop the onChange event.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. No you cannot do that

Comment: can you add a concrete [mre]?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it in a totally different way? Like using state. But I don't believe that since state setting is asynchronous..

Comment: First, handle the onKeyDown event, if the key is backspace, stop onChange event, otherwise let it continue... Also I want to get the keycode to the onChange event so I can use it in a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought it was possible to do it in this way. You can create some auxilliary variable/property and set the keyCode to it in the onKeyDown handler. Then you are able to use this conditionally wherever you want (for me, in the onChange event handler).

Answer (score 1):

```
If you has Select Option: When you click on select tag, onChange and onClick event is fired. I solved this by creating a onClick handler side onChange handle and then calling e.stopPropogation().

<select onClick ="St(event)" onChange ="Tc(event)" >
     <option>Case</option>
</select>

St(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Next');
}

Tc(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Nex here');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prevent backspace, you can store the input's value in state and pass it as prop to the input, and in onChange of the input compare e.target.value with the value stored in state and update the state variable

```
     
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const checkValue = (newValue) => {
    if (value.length < newValue.length) setValue(newValue);
  }; 
    
  <input value={value} onChange={(e) => checkValue(e.target.value)} />
```